# Countable set of sequences - is there a sequence where every element is greater or equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory

I'm looking at this question:

> $\mathrm { N } ^ { \mathrm { N } } : = \{ f : f : \mathrm { N } \rightarrow \mathrm { N } \}$ is the set of all sequences of natural numbers. Let $A= \left\{ f _ { n } \in \mathbb { N } ^ { \mathrm { N } } : n \in \mathrm { N } \right\}$ be any countable subset (finite or infinite) of $\mathrm { N } ^ { \mathrm { N } }$. Is there a sequence $f \in \mathrm { N } ^ { \mathrm { N } }$ where $f _ { n } \leq ^ { * } f\quad \forall  n \in \mathrm { N } $?

My assumption would be that the answer is yes, however I have no idea how to even begin to prove it. I'm guessing the fact that $A$ is countable is important. My only idea would be that, because it is countable, you can possibly order the sequences for each n and then let $f(n)$ be the element of the sequence which is ranked highest, but I really don't know.

I would be thankful for any suggestions!

**Edit:**

> Definition of $f\leq ^ { * } g$ : $\exists m \in \mathbb { N } : \forall n \in \mathbb { N } \text { where } n \geq m \Longrightarrow f ( n ) \leq g ( n )$

Comment: By $f\leq^*g$ do you mean $f(n) \leq g(n) \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was defined elsewhere.

Comment: That is not the usual definition of $\le^*$. Please check what definition you are actually using.

Comment: Sorry again... It was only vaguely defined in two sentences ahead of the question. I did however find this definition in my lecturer's notes later on: $\exists m \in \mathbb { N } \text { : }  \forall n \in \mathbb { N } \text { where } n \geq m \implies f ( n ) \leq g ( n )$

Comment: Please edit that definition into your question.  It is the more common definition.  It ruins the answer you have gotten.

Comment: I've tweaked the definition in the edit to fix a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given a countable $A$ there is a sequence $f$ where all of them are $\le^*$ than $f$.  We set $$f(1)=f_1(1)+1\\
f(2)=\max(f_1(2),f_2(2))+1\\
f(3)=\max(f_1(3),f_2(3),f_3(3))+1\\
f(n)=\max_{i=1}^n(f_i(n))+1$$
This is greater than the first sequence starting at $1$, greater than the second starting by $2$, greater than the $n^{th}$ starting by $n$.  Each of the $\max$ functions has a finite list of arguments, so is well defined.  Diagonalization wins again.

Comment: Thank you! Got it now :)

Comment: To the proposer:  Alternatively let $f(n)=1+\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(n)$.